# the @namespace directive is not working in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I have a Razor class library with a Blazor component and want to set a namespace for that component but I get a compile error:

```
@namespace MY.UI.Blazor.Component;
```

And I get the following compile error:

> Error RZ1014:    The 'namespace' directive expects a namespace name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

remove the `;` Docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#namespace).

```
@namespace MY.UI.Blazor.Component
```

Comment: just for clarification if this is not done, then folder names are used namespace names